# numerically integrate the product of two functions

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I would like to numerically compute the integral of two "resonably smooth" functions,
$$
\int_0^1 f(x) g(x) \,dx.
$$
The values of $f$ and $g$ are known on different uniform grids, and one grid is part of the other. Let say $f$ is known at $0, h, 2h,\dots, 1$ and $g$ at $0, h/5, 2h/5,\dots, 1$.

One way to approximate the integral is to construct the linear interpolants of the values and integrate over their product. Considering the fact the trapezoidal rule has larger error terms than the midpoint rule, perhaps this isn't the smartest idea.

Any hints?

Comment: What is known about $f$? Is it reasonable to assume it is fairly well behaved? If so, interpolating with splines is probably your best bet.

Comment: Well, we'll have to assume _something_, so let's go with some smoothness. Do you have any math to support your claim? Link is fine.

Comment: Splines usually have the best balance between accuracy and simplicity. I'm not all that experienced with numerical techniques so that's about the best information I can give.

Comment: It's not true for linear splines vs. "stairs", see the example in the text. For this reason, I would have doubts about splines being effective here. Another disadvantage is that splines can have negative integral values where all involved values are positive.